# OUTPUT Clause in SQL SERVER error

Tags: sql-server

I created a trigger so that after two friends are added in a social media website this trigger is outputted. I am trying to output a temporary trigger so that as soon they are friend in the output view a statement is shown. What is the syntax error exactly on Output in the following code please? If there could be improvement to the code inform me pls.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [a01].[trg_addedFriend]
ON [a01].[tbl_friends]
AFTER INSERT

AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @FriendA NVARCHAR(45)
    DECLARE @FriendB NVARCHAR(45)

    SELECT @FriendA = ownerAccountID
        FROM inserted;
    SELECT @FriendB = friendAccountID 
        FROM inserted;

    OUTPUT 'Trigger : '+@FriendA+' and '+@FriendB+' become friends.'
    END
GO
```

Comment: Why did you use OUTPUT at all instead of SELECT? Besides, who is going to *read* the result of the trigger?

Comment: The Select is used to fetch the friends IDs and the Output is used to output the following IDs in the view. The question is whether the Output statement is correct.

Comment: The phrases you used are identical. Which is why there is no `OUTPUT` statement. Returning data is performed with SELECT. Perhaps you confused OUTPUT for PRINT? Again no-one would be able to read that message.

Comment: This is an insert trigger. When I code this `OUTPUT inserted*` it is still giving me errors

Comment: There is only an OUTPUT *clause*, used in modification statements to capture the modified rows

Comment: Triggers are SET-BASED.  Abandon your single scalar variables. FriendA and FriendB.  Aka, if you insert 10 rows...all 10 rows will be in the insert. table.

Comment: @NathanAbela there is no such thing as an OUTPUT statement. And a trigger is *not* a statement. Statements are things like INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The Problem is solved @PanagiotisKanavos. I used PRINT instead of OUTPUT and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for his help ! Learning is by doing mistakes

Comment: You're still applying row-by-row in your trigger.  Your trigger is wrong.  Thinking you are done now is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you want the PRINT statement:

   CREATE TRIGGER [a01].[trg_addedFriend]
         ON [a01].[tbl_friends]
       AFTER INSERT

   ```
   AS
       BEGIN

       DECLARE @FriendA NVARCHAR(45)
       DECLARE @FriendB NVARCHAR(45)

       SELECT @FriendA = ownerAccountID
           FROM inserted;
       SELECT @FriendB = friendAccountID 
           FROM inserted;

       Print 'Trigger : '+@FriendA+' and '+@FriendB+' become friends.'
       END
   GO
   ```
2. TRIGGERS ARE SET BASED.  Do NOT apply "row by row" logic in a trigger.

http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2008/06/05/triggers-set-based-not-row-based/